# Hibernate + Oracle, strange null constraint violation with primitive type

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, ora-01400

I just add a new column on an entity and a strange thing is happening.

The entity was previously:

```
int publishedDayNb;


public int getPublishedDayNb() {
    return publishedDayNb;
}

public void setPublishedDayNb(int publishedDayNb) {
    this.publishedDayNb = publishedDayNb;
}
```

And the entity is now:

```
int publishedDayNb;
int publishedDayNbSinceLastPublication;


public int getPublishedDayNb() {
    return publishedDayNb;
}

public void setPublishedDayNb(int publishedDayNb) {
    this.publishedDayNb = publishedDayNb;
}

@Column(name="published_days_since_last_pub")
public int getPublishedDayNbSinceLastPublication() {
    return publishedDayNbSinceLastPublication;
}

public void setPublishedDayNbSinceLastPublication(int publishedDayNbSinceLastPublication) {
    this.publishedDayNbSinceLastPublication = publishedDayNbSinceLastPublication;
}
```

As you can see i've just added a column.

The sql script to do that in database was:

```
alter table mytable add published_days_since_last_pub number(10,0);
update mytable set published_days_since_last_pub=0;
alter table mytable modify published_days_since_last_pub number(10,0) not null;
```

I'm doing a java batch processing, reading a file, inserting new entity entries, and updating existing ones.

It works fine in local and in dev server, but in validation server, i've got this error during a new entity processing (insert)

> BATCH 03/05/2011 06:41:11  WARN
>   [JDBCExceptionReporter.java:77] - SQL
>   Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000 BATCH
>   03/05/2011 06:41:11 ERROR
>   [JDBCExceptionReporter.java:78] -
>   ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
>   ("mydb"."mytable"."PUBLISHED_DAYS_SINCE_LAST_PUB")
>
> BATCH 03/05/2011 06:41:11 ERROR
>   [AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:301]
>   - Could not synchronize database state with session
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
>   could not insert:
>   [com.xxx.myentity]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2262)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2655)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:60)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1001)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
>     at
>   com.xxx.eplatform.websites.webstore.batch.processor.DistrinetDataProcessor$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42d43018.processDistrinetLine()   at
>   com.xxx.eplatform.websites.webstore.batch.services.impl.WebstoreImporterServiceImpl.importDistrinetFile(WebstoreImporterServiceImpl.java:71)
>     at
>   com.xxx.eplatform.websites.webstore.batch.WebstoreImportBatch.execute(WebstoreImportBatch.java:142)
>     at
>   com.xxx.eplatform.websites.webstore.batch.WebstoreImportBatch.main(WebstoreImportBatch.java:104)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException:
>   ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
>   ("mydb"."mytable"."PUBLISHED_DAYS_SINCE_LAST_PUB")
>
> at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:966)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1170)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3339)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3423)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2242)
>     ... 21 more

I don't understand what is wrong since the primitive type i added to the entity is always initialized at 0 so it shouldn't be null.

I've also looked my entity class with javap and it seems it's the right version of the entity: my new attribute is there.

Anyone? Thanks

Comment: The before and after entity code looks the same to me. Am I missing something or did you paste the same code twice?

Comment: Was the 'validation server' restarted in between? (I mean your application running on it)

Comment: Have you tried int publishedDayNbSinceLastPublication = 0;

Comment: Validation server was rebuild, and i found the class in the /target folder (we use maven) to be the good one, with my new attribute. It was restarted. And no i haven't tried int publishedDayNbSinceLastPublication = 0; I'm passing SCJP and the book clearly says that all instance int variable are initialized to 0, and in other environnments it's working so why not on this one?

Answer (score -1):

Just Change int to Integer and see if it help

Comment: actually i want the constraint in db so adding a nullable = false with an Integer, or a primitive type should do the same. Anyway the matter seems to have disappeared